# Best insulation system below a wood floor exposed to nature

Tags: insulation, floor

This area to be insulated is just past the wood deck. You can see chicken wire holding up the old batt insulation that is been torn down by various creatures!  The floor is supported by joists laying across the stone piers.

Considering spray foam but interested in something modular.

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of any pest-proof insulation. I think a protective layer (chicken wire, plywood, etc.) facing the exterior is still going to be a good idea if you want any type of insulation to stay where you put it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foam boards (XPS or EPS). Cut these to the appropriate width, place in the joist bays, glue/screw as needed and fill in the gaps with canned spray foam. Those are fairly resistant to exposure within a crawlspace.

Consider sealing off access into the crawlspace if possible. You'll never keep all the insects out, but covering access holes with chicken wire or mesh will help keep raccoon or other scratching/digging animals out.